# Can you add a Civi Mailing group to an outlook calendar invite?

Tags: email, mailing, calendar, outlook

I have recently created a Mailing group with 138 email addresses. I would like to send a calendar invite in outlook to the mailing group. Is this possible?

Comment: When you say "in outlook", do you mean you want to send the email from your outlook that you have on your computer, or do you mean you want to send them a calendar invite by using the web functions in Civi, which they would then receive in outlook on their computer if they have outlook on their computer?

Comment: are you using an integration extension. i don't 'get' outlook but this sounds like it may be a step in the right direction (maybe not) https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-group-sync